# Difference between Send Email action and Send Email Campaign Message save action

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

Can someone outline the main difference or differences between using the Send Email Campaign Message save action and the Send Email action? Why can't I use the Send Email action in place of the Send Email Campaign Message save action? I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that the Send Email action only sends an e-mail without additional campaigns or analytics interaction. You don't have engagement plans or statistics for your sent e-mail. It's nothing more than sending an HTML-based e-mail to the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Send Email action is basically sending email with System.Net.Mail.

Send Email Campaign Message utilizes Sitecore Email Experience Manager's dispatch pipeline to send emails that can be tracked.